# Function were the number of inputs are varying

Tags: function, optimization, input, julia

I am currently writing a function for solving optimisation problems were the inputs are varing:

```
function solve_problem!(f, x0, lvar, uvar, c, lcon, ucon); #If there are constraints
function solve_problem!(f, x0, lvar, uvar); #If there are no constraints.
```

I have solved this problem by doing as follows;

```
function solve_problem!(f, x0, lvar, uvar, c = 0, lcon = 0, ucon = 0;) 
    if c !=0 
        nlp = ADNLPModel(f_mod, x0, lvar, uvar, c, lcon, ucon);
    else 
        nlp = ADNLPModel(f_mod, x0, lvar, uvar)
    end 
end
```

However, is there a better way of doing this? It is working, but I don't feel like it is good coding. Thank you!

I can't think about another way of doing this as ADNLPModel is an allready existing function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not to use the same approach as is already used by `ADNLPModel`?
Julia is a multiple dispatch language - you can and should have the same method name differentiated by the number of paramaters (and perhaps their types as well).

```
function solve_problem!(f, x0, lvar, uvar, c, lcon = 0, ucon = 0) 
    nlp = ADNLPModel(f_mod, x0, lvar, uvar, c, lcon, ucon)
    do_something(nlp)
end
function solve_problem!(f, x0, lvar, uvar) 
    nlp = ADNLPModel(f_mod, x0, lvar, uvar)
    do_something(nlp)
end
```

If you for some reason were not able to use multiple dispatch and still need to check for parameter assignment I would suggest using `nothing` as the default value rather than `0`.

Comment: Thank you, it was really helpfull! I red a bit about multiple dispatch